# Naturally sort a multi-dimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multidimensional array in php, and I want to naturally sort the array based on key value. The array in question:

```
array(27) {
  ["user1"]=>
  array(1) {
        ["link"]=>
        string(24) "http://twitch.tv/example"
  }
  ["someotheruser"]=>
  array(1) {
        ["link"]=>
        string(24) "http://twitch.tv/example"
  }
  ["anotheruser"]=>
  array(1) {
        ["link"]=>
        string(24) "http://twitch.tv/example"
  }
  // etc...
}
```

I have attempted a few things so far, but I am having no luck. Using `uksort` with natsort doesn't work, and I don't want to have to go as far as writing a custom comparator for natural sorting order if I don't have to. I also attempted sorting the keys individually, however that seemed to not work

```
private function knatsort(&$array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    natsort($keys);
    $new_sort = array();
    foreach ($keys as $keys_2) {
        $new_sort[$keys_2] = $array[$keys_2];
    }
    $array = $new_sort;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Define 'seemed to not work'. BTW, works quite fine [for me](https://eval.in/76800).

Comment: @raina77ow I think I figured out my rather simple error, was I mistook `natsort` for `natcasesort`, so I suppose I could just swap that. Aside from that, I'm not sure why the person who answered with `array_multisort(array_keys($array), SORT_NATURAL, $array);` deleted it, it was a good answer!

Comment: @AbraCadaver you simply needed a bitwise or for the case insensitivity.

Comment: I actually tested it, works fine indeed. )

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something simpler.  Extract the array keys and sort those, sorting the original by that:

```
array_multisort(array_keys($array), SORT_NATURAL, $array);
```

With case insensitivity:

```
array_multisort(array_keys($array), SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE, $array);
```

Answer (score 9):

Even simpler than using `array_multisort`: you can actually provide a sort flag to the built-in `ksort` function to make it sort an array by key in natural order:

```
$arr = array(
    "CFoo" => "xx1",
    "AFoo" => "xx2",
    "1Foo" => "xx3",
    "10AFoo" => "xx4"
);

ksort($arr, SORT_NATURAL);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [1Foo] => xx3
    [10AFoo] => xx4
    [AFoo] => xx2
    [CFoo] => xx1
)
```

If you want to apply it recursively to a multidimensional array, you can write a simple function for that:

```
function natksort_multi(&$arr = array()) {
    ksort($arr, SORT_NATURAL);

    foreach (array_keys($arr) as $key) {
        if (is_array($arr[$key])) {
            natksort_multi($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would bet ksort($arr, SORT_NATURAL); is more optimal than uksort($arr, "strnatcmp"); due to the natural sort being called as a callback in uksort

Answer (score 7):

Check out [strnatcmp();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php)
This is a natural sort by key function using it:

```
function knatsort(&$arr){return uksort($arr,function($a, $b){return strnatcmp($a,$b);});}
```

Works in place with the speed and return value of uksort.
Use it like this:

```
knatsort($array);
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Building off @AbraCadaver's answer from earlier, I managed to put together a one-line solution using a bitwise-or for combining natural sort with case-insensitivity.

```
array_multisort(array_keys($this->streams), SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE , $this->streams);
```

Where `$this->streams` is my multidimensional array. This seemed to work the best.